# SQL add additional ID for product variant

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I'm building a table that tracks physical products variants' (like a T-shirt with print various colorways) with a foreign and primary key of `product_id` and the primary key of `variant_id`. I would like the format of the `variant_id` to be auto-incrementing after the `product_id`. So if there is a product with id 123, and I would add variants to that product, that it starts with 123-1, then 123-2 for the second variant, and just auto-increments for each variant.

What I now have is an auto-incrementing `variant_id` and `product_id`, but without that format, it's harder to process.

How can I configure this in the table setup? And what is the conventional way of doing this, would that be auto-incrementing both without a format and writing a query to format it?

**Current variants table:**
[image: Current variants table]

I've created this [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb492e4cf059820e30ca51373e289692) that first creates a products table and then a variants table. This works however, the `variant_id` isn't in the desired format, because it auto increments its own value instead of taking `product_id` into the mix.

In this DBfiddle I also used `ENGINE = MyISAM` which I'm not sure is efficient for the database design.

Here is the current output of a test variants table, in which the `variant_id` of 1 should be 1-1 and the `variant_id` of 2 should be 3-1 (product number 3, first variant). I inserted these by specifying the `product_id` and `variant_name`.

[image: variants table]

Comment: Enumerate in a group in CTE (ROW_NUMBER with proper ordering) and update. For to set next number during insertion use trigger.

Comment: @Akina I've added a screenshot of the current table setup, is there a way to add an auto-increment function in the desired format, with each variant starting at 1, in the table setup, or is this desired format only possible during data insertion?

Comment: you could use a trigger function and set it to trigger before each insert. inside it you can query for the latest variant id and set the new one to any format you want.

Comment: "Table setup" must be the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` query, any other is not useful/complete. Look does MyISAM engine and autoincremented secondary column in primary key is safe for you... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e11d8382d38581d36a72f6214eeccaa

Comment: @Akina thank you for that link, I've been playing around with the code but the only thing that is missing is that the `product_id` should be a foreign key. I've tried to recreate the links query with 2 tables: `products` and `variants`, with the `variants` containing a `product_id` foreign key, but I got the error that there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.
Also, what is the purpose of the `ENGINE = MyISAM` command?

Comment: *but I got the error that there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.* Provide a fiddle with the error. * what is the purpose of the ENGINE = MyISAM command?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html And remember - this engine is NOT transactional.

Comment: @Akina is the MyISAM engine a requirement for this to work? As the not transactional doesn't seem optimal.
Here's the fiddle I've created with the setup:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb492e4cf059820e30ca51373e289692

Comment: The error message tells about `variant_id` - it is autoincrement but is not a primary key.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Fixed that, but now it is saying, `Failed to open the referenced table 'products'`. I looked up that error and it seems to be a chicken and egg problem, where one table isn't created yet but already mentioned. However, the products table is created first, and also correctly. I'm not sure what's going wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Nuxurious, it seems like you've made some progress, however, it might be not very visual for the community to see your current state. Please consider updating your question adding some information about what was completed and what's the current issue. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Farid. Tested some more and updated the question with the current problems.